# How to write new rules from code behined in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I have applied URL rewrite in my application and define some rules in web.config as

```
  <modulesSection>
        <rewriteModule>
            <rewriteOn>true</rewriteOn>
            <rewriteRules>              
                <rule source="About/About-test" destination="About/About.aspx"/>
                <rule source="test-In-Media" destination="Others/MediaUpdates.aspx"/>
                <rule source="Home" destination="MasterPage/HomePage.aspx"/>                
            </rewriteRules>
        </rewriteModule>
</modulesSection>

<httpModules>
            <add name="RewriteModule" type="RewriteModule.RewriteModule, RewriteModule"/>
            <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </httpModules>
```

ok I have found my solution..I have used following code snippets..

```
 RewriteModuleSectionHandler cfg =(RewriteModuleSectionHandler)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("modulesSection/rewriteModule");

            if (!cfg.RewriteOn) return;
            string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path;

            if (path.Length == 0) return;


            XmlNode xmlNode = cfg.XmlSection.SelectSingleNode("rewriteRules");


            if( xmlNode != null )
            {

            }
```

now how can I add new rule in   format???

Answer (score 0):

can you please be more specific which type of rule you want to add or modify?

for changing web .config through application please go through following article.

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=102